# yii2 validating array of inputs

Tags: yii2

I have following data :

```
Array
(
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 100
        )

    [volume] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 100
        )

    [urgency] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 100
        )

    [importance] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 100
        )
)
```

And I created DynamicModel for it with rules "each value should be integer" (added in 2.0.4).

```
$view_model = DynamicModel::validateData(compact('category', 'volume', 'urgency', 'importance'), [
        [['category', 'volume', 'urgency', 'importance'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
    ]);
```

In view I have:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'category[0]')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'category[1]')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'category[2]')->textInput() ?>
    ...
    <?= $form->field($model, 'importance[2]')->textInput() ?>
```

Problem is, when I submit form with "d" in first input, I have errors on each "category" input:
[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: Each validator validates array values associated with specific model attribute.
So if one of array values doesn't validate the whole attribute considered invalid.
In other words you don't have information which array element have caused validation error.

Comment: @aalgogiver of course he can get information about which array element have caused validation error. It is easily possible via: `$view_model->getErrors()`.

Comment: @aalgogiver So it is right behaviour of the framework?

Comment: Yes, error belongs to attribute. If you had an array of models than each model could have its own error on id field , for example.

Comment: @aalgogiver You mean this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html ?

Comment: @Ilya Chase Yes, it describes the same idea.

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour I doubt it. As it described in docs only attribute names returned
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getErrors%28%29-detail

Comment: @aalgogiver Please read document carefully, `Errors for all attributes or the specified attribute. Empty array is returned if no error. Note that when returning errors for all attributes, the result is a two-dimensional array,...`

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour I think we misunderstand each other.
Can you provide code which returns array index of element for category attribute which caused validation error? In question above this is zero-indexed element `category[0]`

Comment: @aalgogiver `DynamicModel`

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour Ok, to make things clear.
You have an array of category ids from the question  `[category] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 100
        )`

How can we get 0 as index of element which caused validation error?

Comment: @aalgogiver DynamicModel is containing an array of data.

Comment: @aalgogiver Take a look :  `$category=[100,100,100];
        $volume=[100,100,100,'b'];
        $urgency=[100,100,100];
        $view_model = \yii\base\DynamicModel::validateData(compact($category,$volume,$urgency), [
                    [['category', 'volume', 'urgency'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer','skipOnError'=>TRUE]],
        ]);
        $view_model->validate('volume',FALSE);` Now, if you get `$view_model->getErrors();` you can see the error is only for `volume`.

Comment: @Ali MasudianPour DynamicModel extends Model which has getErrors() method which returns multidimentional array **with attribute names as keys**. Category attribute has array as value and is validated with `each` validation rule. For example, second element (1-index) of this array isn't valid. There's no way to have element's index which isn't valid because getErrors() only returns **attribute names** as keys. There's no any indexes. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry for disturbing an old topic, but I have the same issue. Have you got any success addressing those error messages to the index the belong to? @IlyaChase

Answer (score 3):

You can use Each validator
Info: This validator has been available since version 2.0.4.

```
[
    // checks if every category ID is an integer
    ['categoryIDs', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
]
```

This validator only works with an array attribute. It validates if every element of the array can be successfully validated by a specified validation rule. In the above example, the categoryIDs attribute must take an array value and each array element will be validated by the integer validation rule.

```
rule: an array specifying a validation rule. The first element in the array specifies the class name or the alias of the validator. The rest of the name-value pairs in the array are used to configure the validator object.
allowMessageFromRule: whether to use the error message returned by the embedded validation rule. Defaults to true. If false, it will use message as the error message.

Note: If the attribute value is not an array, it is considered validation fails and the message will be returned as the error message.
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is applicable to ajax request scenarios**

> In your controller

```
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\Response;

public function actionCreate()
{
    $models = [
        'model1' => new Category, 
        'model2' => new Category, 
    ];

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $validate = [];
        $validate = array_merge(ActiveForm::validateMultiple($models), $validate);
        // If you need to validate another models, put below.
        // $validate = array_merge(ActiveForm::validate($anotherModel), $validate);

        return $validate;
    }

    if (Model::loadMultiple($models, Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        foreach($models as $key => $model) {
            $model->save();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'models' => $models,
    ]);
}
```

> In your view

```
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableClientValidation' => false, 
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true, 
    ]);
?>

<?= $form->field($models['model1'], '[model1]name')->textInput(); ?>
<?= $form->field($models['model2'], '[model2]name')->textInput(); ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Create') ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```